# Determine if an arc represents an reflex or acute angle

Tags: geometry, angle, points

I have this seemingly simple but very confusing problem.

Given I have a set of vertices (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)...... representing an arc. The points can either be clockwise or counter clockwise, but are all similarly ordered.
And I know the center of the arc (xc,yc).

How can I tell if the arc subtends an acute/obtuse or reflex angle?

One obvious solution is to take the difference of atan2((last_pt)-(center)) and atan2((first_pt)-(center))). But if the arc goes through the point where PI become -PI, this method breaks down.

Also, since the arc points are derived from a rather noisy pixelated picture, the vertices are not exactly smooth.

[Picture of a acute and reflex arc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f4Jt.png)

I cant wrap my brain around solving this problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're in the right direction. Notice that if the difference you already have `atLP-atFP` is `<0`then just add 2PI to get the right inner angle.

Answer (score 0):

Working with 2D angles is a pain for the reason you described, so it's better to work with vector math instead, which is rotationally invariant.

Define the 2D *cross-product*, `A ^ B = Ax * By - Ay * Bx`. This is positive if `A` is clockwise rotated relative to `B`, and vice versa.

The logic:

- Compute `C = (last_pt - center) ^ (first_pt - center)`
- If `C = 0`, the arc is either closed or 180-degree (forgot the name for this)
- If `C > 0`, the arc must either be **(i)** clockwise *and* acute/obtuse or **(ii)** anti-clockwise *and* reflex
- If `C < 0`, the opposite applies

Pseudocode:

```
int arc_type(Point first, Point last, Point center, bool clockwise)
{
    // cross-product
    float C = (last.x - center.x) * (first.y - center.y)
            - (last.y - center.y) * (first.x - center.x);

    if (Math.abs(C) < /* small epsilon */)
        return 0;                      // 180-degree

    return ((C > 0) ^ clockwise) ? 1   // reflex
                                 : -1; // acute / obtuse
}
```

Note that if you don't have prior knowledge of whether the arc is clockwise or anti-, you can use the same cross-product method on adjacent points. You need to ensure that the order of the points is *consistent* - if not you can, again using the cross-product, sort them by (relative) angle.